# Crash C++ application using sprintf_s without specifying string length

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a c++ application, in which customer reported a crash.But the crash is not easily reproducible.
After analysing some logs and all i found that the crash may occure in between the following code portions. Please tell me there is  any chance of getting crashed the application if i have these code statements in it?

```
    //Tesrt
    std::string strAppName = "App1\0";
    int nSize = 10;
    sprintf_s(szBuff, "The appname %s have %d dependancies ", strAppName.c_str(), nSize);
    //Then use the szBuff to log to a text file
    //Test end
```

Comment: The null character in the literal assigned to `strAppName` is redundant.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I think you are confusing `sprintf_s` with `sprintf`. Also, assuming an `int` to be 32-bit is not very portable.

Comment: @NiklasB.: OK. I got the point, since this is the safe version from Windows. About `int`, I'm not sure if there is any implementation with 64-bit, though (according to Wikipedia).

Comment: `sprintf_s` either takes a `char` array by reference OR a pointer to `char` and a size parameter.

Comment: @Charles: Yeah, my mistake. I didn't look close enough.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've not provided the [correct arguments to `sprintf_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
int sprintf_s(
   char *buffer,
   size_t sizeOfBuffer,
   const char *format [,
      argument] ... 
);
```

`sprintf_s` takes a `size_t` as it's second argument (the size of `szBuff`), but you've not provided that. Instead, you've given it a `const char *` where that parameter should be. The only way to have compiled this is for you to have ignored compiler warnings.

So what `sprintf_s` is seeing is:
buffer to print into 
large number of characters allowed to go into buffer
`strAppName.c_str()` as the format string

In other words, this isn't doing anything like what you want. Provide the size of `szBuff` as the second parameter, and I'll bet your problems go away.

And yes, given what you've done I'd expect crashes all over the place.

Comment: szBuff is declared as follows  char szBuff[1024];

Comment: Unless `szBuff` really is an array and he is using the template version. (Aside: how someone can develop a template overload where the parameters shift around in such a dangerous way and still use `_s` as a suffix, I don't know.)

Comment: @Charles: Wow, didn't even see that. Really bad design. Sorry, Minnu, maybe I was wrong there.

Comment: Ok, but i have another code portion as follows "sprintf_s(szBuff, "Handle %d has %d items ",nSize,nItemSize) ie, with fixed integer arguments ..is it become problem?